# Is it really not possible to select all content of all pages at the same time?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

In Acrobat DC it seems that the standard 'Select All' command doesn't have the capacity to select all content of all pages.  It only does it for the current page in view.

With this limitation in mind, if I want to change the type style/size/color of content across a document how can I do it ?

I'm so surprised by this limitation of the software... surly there must be a work around ?

Comment: A PDF is sort of a "baked cake". The "recipe" is the working document that was used to export the PDF from the layout program etc. So editing PDFs is raw and cumbersome. I don't think you can select all content on all pages in one go. But you can look into using Preflight Fixups to perform global changes. I don't think it can't change font properties though, but it can change colors and more technical stuff. I'm using the Enfocus PitStop Pro plugin at work to fix client PDFs. Powerful tool. Can probably change fonts, but I've never tried - can't see how it should end well really. 

Comment: @Wolff you can change font but that does not guarantee the linespacing works and no reflow. So you really dont want to change it.

Comment: PostScript is a programming language. You could get into the code and make changes to it that way, but you would have to be really knowledgeable about the language; it's way too complicated to describe here. Another possibility is to convert it to Word format, where fonts are more easily changed.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Adobe InDesign, the `Select All` command selects what is in the *viewport*. If you can't *see* a page, it won't factor into "all".

If you zoom out and set the page display to `Enable scrolling`, you can get multiple pages within the viewport. Then `Select All` will select all on the *visible* pages.

But... changing type size, color, style for *everything* in a PDF is really not how things are customarily done as @Wolff mentions in his comment. PDFs are end formats and edit ability is somewhat limited. Typically one would go back to the *originating application* to make any edits. 99% of documents, particularly text-heavy documents, don't *start* as PDFs, they are output to PDF from some *other* application. Acrobat, Reader, et al., are *not* layout or design tools.

Answer (score 0):

PDF is not meant to be a editable format. The way you apply global changes is to use fixups, no need to select anything. They can do prettymuch anything you want, but are really, really hard to author.

Changing things like font may or may not work out for you. Most likely not. A PDF file does not contain text boxes, it contains graphic description. As such the authoring application may have taken some liberties with said text.

The end result is that while you could change font and its size, acrobat has no knowledge of how to reflow the text*. Worse authoring application might have done kerning with graphic instructions so now even your words nolonger align with eachother.

Changing color is much more likely to work out though, since layout does not need to change. I do this all the time for making color documents tresholded black.

You will find that most people would simply avoid doing this if they have any other options. In fact for many even suggesting a pdf can be edited is preposterous. If you do not, fine but expect it to be an order of magnitude or two of more work than you expect.

* depends there may be hints but then you cant organize it the same way.